# why react app not compiling if react project created by create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I created project using `npx create-react-app my-app`. It will works on that same day but when I resume/start work on very next day, project isn't compiling and didn't start on server.

Please see below screenshot to view the error:

[image]

Dependancies:

[image]

Comment: Run `npm install` before you run `npm start`

Comment: Tried it right now but it appears the error: 

`(node:8208) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8208) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.`

Comment: @JohnOcean It seems like CRA issue. the issue reported at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12035 . Also, I just wonder your node version

Comment: @HumanoidMk.12 it's v18.16.1

Comment: I don't think CRA is still actively mainatained. CRA is not recomended anymore in the new react docs https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project.